# Replace words starting with particular character in R

Tags: regex, r

I want to replace all words that begin with a given character with a different word. Tried `gsub` and `str_replace_all` but with little success. In this example I want to replace all words starting with R with MM. `gsub` replaces properly only once:

```
gsub("^R*\\w+", "MM", "Red, Rome, Ralf")

# [1] "MM, Rome, Ralf"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

You must either remove the string start anchor (`^`) or work with a vector of words:

```
gsub("\\bR\\w+", "MM", "Red, Rome, Ralf")
#[1] "MM, MM, MM"


gsub("^R\\w+", "MM", c("Red", "Rome", "Ralf"))
#[1] "MM" "MM" "MM"
```

Also, you probably want "R" instead of "R*", since the latter can match 0 or more instances of "R". The regexes above match only words with 2 or more characters, the first of which must be "R". The last regex only matches words at the beginning of the string.

Thanks @flodel for pointing out the missing word boundary "\b" in the first regex!